# add touch event for iconElementLeft of AppBar - material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```
<AppBar
  iconElementLeft={<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>}
  onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={()=>{this.handleClose()}}
/>
```

how to add click, touch event for this example?
this code is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both `onLeftIconButtonTouchTap` and `onRightIconButtonTouchTap` don't work. Use `IconButton`'s `onClick` event instead:

```
<IconButton onClick={this.handleClose}>...
```

Comment: If `react-tap-event-plugin`  is injected, they do work.

Comment: Regardless of the plugin, it doesn't work on material-ui 0.15.0. Have you actually tested it before posting?

Comment: I run production apps with `0.15.4` version, everything seems to be ok. Will try with `0.15.0`

Comment: Thanks for posting the version where it works, I will have to update mines as well.

Comment: Tested with `0.15.0`. Works well.

Comment: Maybe your react is <15? react-tap-event-plugin - 1.0.0 and react -15.1.0 here

Comment: React version is `15.0.0`

Comment: works with me.
my version 
  "material-ui": "^0.15.4",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",

Answer (score 1):

In order to make `touchTap` events work in `material-ui`, you must use `react-tap-event-plugin` dependency. Most probably you didn't inject this plugin at the start of your app.

Be sure that it is installed:

```
npm i --save react-tap-event-plugin
```

And injected:

```
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin'
injectTapEventPlugin()
```

More information [here](http://www.material-ui.com/#/get-started/installation)

Comment: I have already done this and the touch event is working fine in other places, the problem is with the iconElementLeft, I cant get it to work. also on the same component the title touch event is working